# How can I compute this integral $\int \cos^{2}\left(t\sqrt{x^{2}-1}\right)dx $

Tags: integration, trigonometry

How can I compute this integral $$\int \cos^{2}\left(t\sqrt{x^{2}-1}\right)dx
 $$

Even when I use Maxima, it does not give result.

Thank you very much.

Comment: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+cos%5E2%28t%28x%5E2-1%29%5E0.5%29dx&x=0&y=0. Did you see it

Comment: Yes, but what do you mean?

Comment: That's almost impossible

Answer (score 5):

Your integral is related with the Fourier cosine transform of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}$, that can be computed through Fresnel integrals, but is not an elementary function. For instance:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{1}^{M}\cos(t\sqrt{x^2-1})\,dx &=& \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{M^2-1}}\frac{\cos(tu)}{\sqrt{u+1}}\,du\\ &=& \frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{1+\sqrt{M^2-1}}\frac{\cos(tu)\cos(t)+\sin(tu)\sin t}{\sqrt{u}}\,du\\&=&\int_{1}^{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{M^2-1}}}\cos(t)\cos(tv^2)+\sin(t)\sin(tv^2)\,dv.\end{eqnarray*}$$
Obviously, $\cos^2(z) = \frac{1+\cos(2z)}{2}$.

Comment: Could you explain it more precisely? Or just give me some links about it.

Comment: @chuyenvien94: I have just provided the expansion in terms of Fresnel integrals (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral)

Comment: What are your $u$ and $v$?

Comment: @chuyenvien94: that is trivial, too. $u=\sqrt{x^2-1}$ and $v=u^2=x^2-1$.

Comment: How can we deal with $M=\infty$?

Comment: Anyway your computation is amazing

Comment: @chuyenvien94: we may deal with the $M=+\infty$ case through Dirichlet's test and the fact that $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(u^2)\,du = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\cos(u^2)\,du = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}.$$

Comment: @chuyenvien94: you're welcome.

Comment: I checked your computations and don't understand why we get the first "="

Comment: The dominator should be square root of $(u^2+1)$